# How to use Laravel Sanctum with two different frontend and backend domains?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

Frontend: `localhost:3002`

Backend: `sanctum.local`

How to config these two fields in the `env` file:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

when I try to login I get 419 unknown status.

Answer (score 2):

add:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="localhost,127.0.0.1"
SESSION_DOMAIN=".sanctum.local"
```